# shuffling upper 32 bits with lower 32 bits in m128

Tags: c, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm working with C intrinsics (SSE/SSE2 only) right now, and i have a m128 value with 4 floats in it.
Are there any possibility of shifting / shuffling / moving the most upper 32 bits to most lower 32 bits?

Example :
I have {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f} in m128 and i want to make {4.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f} out of it. (the values in beetween may be erased).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that via [`shufps xmm, xmm, imm8` instruction](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2&expand=3407,5648,5197&text=shuffle), with which you can statically select which input word should be stored for each output word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int main(void) {
    float array[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f};
    __m128 data;
    printf("before : %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f\n", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
    data = _mm_loadu_ps(array);
    data = _mm_shuffle_ps(data, data, 0x27);
    _mm_storeu_ps(array, data);
    printf("after  : %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f\n", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `_MM_SHUFFLE` macro can be useful to compose the `0x27` constant. It makes it more apparent which elements go where.